# NSButton with two or more actions

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbutton

I am iOS developer and I want to develop a Mac app (it's basically a "port" from an iOS app). In IB in iOS is very easy to connect one UIButton to two or more actions. I have noticed that in a Mac App I only can connect a NSButton to a single action. Is there a way to connect an NSButton to more than one action?

Comment: Why not just have the button call a common handler that calls two methods?  Seems simpler than having multiple targets for a singular action.

Comment: you can call multiple methods inside the action like [self method] .

Comment: First of all, in ios you have less view area so you use one button with multiple actions. in osx you have a big screen area, you can create multiple buttons..isn't it

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I suspect that the real reason is because AppKit controls store targets and selectors based on the control event rather than on the selector-target pair.

Comment: @CodaFi: yes I agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to connect an NSButton to more than one action?

**NO**. This is not supported in OSX Cocoa applications.

You need to `setAction:`  yourself based on conditions, But only one at a time can be used.

In case you want to call two methods(actions), in the IBAction method you need to call them.

```
-(IBAction)multipleActions:(id)sender{
    [self method1:sender];
    [self method2:sender];
}
```

Comment: I though Cocoa and Cocoa Touch had little differences but I see there are a lot of differences.